# neo4j how to use where conditionally

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have the following query:

```
MATCH (u: User {id: '...'})-[r:EXECUTING]->(journey: Journey)
WHERE r.progress > 0 AND r.progress < 100
RETURN journey;
```

It loads all journeys that are attached to a user with `:EXECUTING` if the relationship's `progress` property is between 1 and 100.

Now I want to add a condition for the part behind the `AND` --> so the `WHERE` should only be `r.progress > 0` (without the `AND` ...).
I saw that there are `CASE`/`WHEN`/`THEN` but think that there must be a quicker solution?

Example "The where should check r.progress to be between 0 and 50 if a certain variable is false. If the variable is true, it should check r.progress to be between 0 and 100"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please give us examples. thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Maybe try and write the query as you would like it to be, even if it's not valid Cypher? Or describe the condition in plain English?

Comment: I tried to explain in English - I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description

> Example "The where should check r.progress to be between 0 and 50 if a certain variable is false. If the variable is true, it should check r.progress to be between 0 and 100"

I'd write the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (
     (variable = FALSE AND (r.progress > 0 AND r.progress < 50 ))
     OR
     (variable = TRUE AND (r.progress > 0 AND r.progress < 100 ))
)
```

But not sure it is "quicker" than a CASE/WHEN.

Comment: It's not really quicker, but it's a different solution than CASE/WHEN. I'll accept this one - thank you.